# ag-grid tooltip tooltipField not showing all caracters including special ones

Tags: angular, tooltip, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid cell content that can have special characters displayed without any issue.

Example of such string:

```
 510121747%20(9)%20(2019-10-12%2017:05:17.479420) ({'res':%20"{'update1': 1, 'warnings1': 1, 'modified1': 1
```

So now when I use `tooltipField` this way:

```
{
    headerName: 'Task',
    field: 'task',
    minWidth: 200,
    valueFormatter: function (params) {
      return encodeURI(params.value);
    },
    tooltipField: 'task'
}
```

The tooltip is not displayed exactly as we see the string inside the cell, and the tooltip is truncated as well, so I can see only this value in this case:

```
510121747(9)(2019-10-12 17:05:17.479420)({'res':
```

I've tried to use `encodeURI` function in the valueFormater but that did not work.

So not sure yet how I can get the tooltip to show the exact string displayed in the cell

Do someone have any idea how to fix this ?